# Fuzzy NSDictionary - use nearest key

Tags: objective-c, nsdictionary

I have a list of around 4000 numbers e.g: `{10, 20, 30, 40, 50,...}`

Each number is a key in an `NSDictionary`, so I can fetch the object associated with a number, e.g.

```
[NSDictionary objectForKey:[NSNumber numberWithInt:20];
```

However if the key is not in the dictionary, I'd like to find the nearest key (assuming there is a meaningful relationship between values, in my example, 10>20>30 etc).

So e.g.

```
[NSDictionary objectForKey:[NSNumberWithInt:19]] would return the value for key:20.
```

Or is there another data structure that would be more appropriate for doing this? I'd thought of using a sorted NSArray, where the key would be the array index, then if object was null keep incrementing the array pointer until the object is found, however this would result in a sparsly populated array with 999,999 elements :)

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Essentially you need to keep a sorted list (NSMutableArray) of keys. To find a key use the `indexOfObject:inSortedRange:options:usingComparator:` method of NSArray passing in `NSBinarySearchingInsertionIndex` as the options which will perform a binary search giving you an index even if it doesnt find the exact element. You'll have to fetch both keys yourself and compare them.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your list of numbers is in ascending order you could do a **binary search** in the array.
So when looking for the key x, you would start at index array.length/2, compare the key at that position with x and continue with the left part if it was greater than x or with the right part if it was less than x. Continue until you've found the closest key to x.

Thats very fast (in your case about log(4000) ~ 12 array lookups) and does not need additional storage.